# Can I use qtcreator for making GUI on C?

Tags: c, qt-creator

I have a university project for my first semester. I've written a C source file, but I want to create a GUI for my project. Can it be done with QT creator?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO. That said, of course you can! It's a very good IDE and you can work with *cmake* or *qmake* or *qbs* projects easily and if you don't know what that means (sorry for saying this), you shouldn't be writing any c gui application.

Comment: @iharob QT it for C++, although you can introduce some c code by extern "c" directive, but till you will not be able to interact with QT classes. i advice Osama to switch to GTK

Comment: Try writing a dll interface for your c code

Comment: Please STOP!!!! Y have worked on a *xfce4* panel plugin with qt using cmake and it's simply perfect! Only very few things would not look right like vararg functions on some other things, but since c++ tried to be similar to c many things work correctly. Another problem is that some times it would remove `struct` automatically.

Comment: @OsamaArif it's not **QT** it's *Qt*, and *Qt* is not the saame as qtcreator. *Qt* is a c++ library with a very wide range of classes and functions that make cross platform development very easy while qtcreator is an IDE. You can use c functions in c++ programs, just need to tell the compiler not to mangle their names using `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 2):

You are apparently confused.

It's not [**QT**](http://www.apple.com/es/quicktime/download/)<sup>1</sup>, it's [Qt](http://www.qt.io/developers/) "*lower case t*", and [*qtcreator*](http://www.qt.io/ide/) is not *Qt*.

You can write *Qt* applications without *qtcreator* or [*qmake*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-overview.html)<sup>3</sup>, in fact I have a large *Qt* application which uses [*cmake*](https://cmake.org/) as a build system, and you know [*KDE*](https://www.kde.org/) uses *cmake* (with [automoc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html), which was originally part of *KDE*'s source code) too.

Also, you can use [c](/questions/tagged/c) libraries in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), in fact you can use C libraries pretty much anywhere - unlike C++, with which you can't.

One complication about using C functions in C++ code is that C++ changes the names of functions to allow function/method overloading (although methods are not relevant for C). But even though, you can even create a plugin interface for C++ classess by writing *"C"*<sup>2</sup> functions that would create and destroy instances of classes.

To avoid the *name mangling* problem there is `extern "C"`, so say that you have a C function in a header file "*function.h*"

```
void c_function(void);
```

and you want to use it in C++ code, you do this

```
extern "C" {
#    include "function.h"
}
```

and now you can call the `c_function()` from the C++ code.

**Conclusion**

- You can write a *Qt* graphical user interface and use your C code in it, that doesn't require anything special at all except `extern "C"`.
- You can write a C (maybe *gtk*) graphical user interface using qtcreator, and it's actually very nice how the work together. I would recomend *cmake* as a build system in this case, although in principle *qmake* should do the job as well.
- You can use [*PyGTK*](http://www.pygtk.org/), [*PyQt*](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) or even [*Python's TkInter*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) to write the graphical user interface, because you can create a [python](/questions/tagged/python) module from the *C* code.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>QT actually stands for QuickTime.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Not really *C* functions, because you need to be able to use the `new` operator in order to create the instances of the classes, so it's really a C++ function which is declared with `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling.</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>Before there was no *qtcreator*, but *Qt* was there and KDE 3 did use *Qt* without *cmake*, just autotools.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No, to create a gui project you have to use c++ code

Comment: You can perfectly write any kind of c code including but not limited to *gtk* gui application with qtcreator and it works great for that.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is not c, but you can.

**Option 1**
That doesn't mean you will have to change your c source file.Just write a dll interface that will provide an API to the c layer.

**Option 2**
And also since C is some how related to c++,I guess it would be so easy to add an object oriented nature to your code hence not changing the logic of your code leaving it the same

Comment: It's the other way around, there was first c and c++ tried to be like it.

Answer (score -2):

this is a hello world tutorial from Qt website, it is in C++, and it is a challenge for @iharob to translate it to "C". any other is welcome that makes it more instructive.

```
/****************************************************************
**
** Qt tutorial 1
**
****************************************************************/

#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    QPushButton hello( "Hello world!", 0 );
    hello.resize( 100, 30 );

    a.setMainWidget( &hello );
    hello.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: @iharob how can this be translated to C?

Comment: Where did I say that I had the power to convert garbage into poetry?

Comment: Here you go [A c gtk+ project with qtcreator as promised in my answer](http://wikisend.com/download/859260/example.tar.gz)